# HTML Button to "Pass" String to PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm an HTML newbie who is struggling to come up to speed fast.  In the below code, I want the user to be able to enter a text string into the text field, then click "Submit".  When the button is clicked, the user's string is "passed" to PHP code, which simply prints out the string for POC:

```
<html>
        <body>

        <form method="post">
                Input a String:  <input type="text" name="userInput"><br>
                <input type ="submit"/>
        </form>

        <?php
                if(array_key_exists('userInput', $_POST)) {
                        function1();
                }
                function function1() {
                        $userInput = $_POST['userInput'];
                        echo "User input was: \"$userInput\"\n";
                }
        ?>

        </body>
</html>
```

FULL DISCLOSURE  ::  This is code adapted [from here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-call-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button/).  I'm pretty sure the PHP code is not being engaged, but I can't figure out why.  Thank you.

EDIT :: As per @Barmar, I've added `$userInput = $_POST['userInput'];` to the PHP function.  The code still doesn't work, alas.

Comment: It looks like it should work. Is it in a `.php` file?

Comment: What do you see when you submit the form?

Comment: If you input some text and submit it the text will be available as $_POST['userInput']. You can also upload the value using AJAX.

Comment: Would be an idea to 1. name the function with something meaningful, and 2. use arguments so you can use it from several contexts, instead of locking it to a variable outside its scope. ```function say_user_input($input) {
  echo "User input was: \"$input\"\n";
}
if(!empty($_POST['userInput'])) {
  say_user_input($_POST['userInput']);
}```

Comment: @Barmar Thanks Barmar.  Actually, you see the entire HTML file in this post.  For once, I was able to crunch it down to SO postable code.  Then this webpage loads, you can see the "Input a String:  " text, the text box, and the SUBMIT button.  But when you type in a string and click SUBMIT, nothing happens.

Comment: @MarkusAO Thanks Markus!  I'm in meetings all day today, I'll try your solution first thing tomorrow, will let you know how it goes

Comment: You never set the variable `$userInput`. You need `$userInput = $_POST['userInput'];` in the function.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks Barmar.  See OP, now edited with your added line.  I'm afraid that didn't do the trick, however...

Comment: I said "in the function". If you do it outside the function you need `global $userInput;`. You need to read a tutorial on PHP variables and scopes.

Comment: And you shouldn't set the variable until after you check if the key exists with `array_key_exists`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, so you did say in the function.  I've revised the edit and the code.  It is still not working, I'm afraid, but thank you

Comment: Are you running this on an actual server that's running PHP, or just locally in your browser? Assuming it's on a web server, have you checked the logs? Can you run a simple PHP script of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`?

Comment: The amended version works on my server. Is the file named with a PHP extension? Is your web server properly serving PHP pages? Copy the undernoted code into a file called test.php and run it, what do you get? <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: @j08691 Thanks j08691.  My server has PHP installed, version 8.1.2.  I am testing by pointing a browser at the server and clicking a link which loads the above code.

Comment: Do you know what webserver (Apache, NGINX etc) you're using? Some of them have posted data disabled by default/ require configuring to make sure they actually pass the post body to php